# kiosk - content updating

Tags: apache, kiosk

I have a kiosk computer that runs IE 9.0 "http://localhost" to display content on the D:\ drive.

I want to be able to write a program that when a USB flash drive is inserted, it will copy the files from the flash drive and then reload the localhost page. The computer runs XAMPP (Apache and PHP). How can I accomplish this?

I was thinking of using Windows Task Scheduler and run it every 5 minutes, but sometimes it can take longer than 5 minutes to copy files. And if I set it to 15min to be safe, then the person updating the kiosk has to wait approx 15 minutes for the task to run again, plus the time to copy.

Any help, ideas, or direction on how to proceed would be GREAT!

Comment: If you figure this out, make sure that physical access to the machine is not possible without unlocking a cabinet or something first.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a Windows service that periodically (once every 10-20 seconds?) checks for files on the drive letter that the thumb drive uses? If files are found, copy them to the proper locations.

Does the computer have internet access? Normally these things would just be pushed out to the computer remotely.